# Fixing dates that were coerced into the wrong format

Tags: r

I have a large df with dates that were accidentally coerced into the wrong format.

Data:

```
id <- c(1:12)  
date <- c("2014-01-03","2001-08-14","2001-08-14","2014-06-02","2006-06-14", "2006-06-14",
          "2014-08-08","2014-08-08","2008-04-14","2009-12-13","2010-09-14","2012-09-14")
df <- data.frame(id,date)
```

Structure:

```
    id  date
1   1   2014-01-03
2   2   2001-08-14
3   3   2001-08-14
4   4   2014-06-02
5   5   2006-06-14
6   6   2006-06-14
7   7   2014-08-08
8   8   2014-08-08
9   9   2008-04-14
10  10  2009-12-13
11  11  2010-09-14
12  12  2012-09-14
```

The data set only includes, or rather *should* only include the years `2014` and `2013`. The dates `2001-08-14` and `2006-06-14` are most likely `2014-08-01` and `2014-06-06`, respectively.

Output:

```
    id  date
1   1   2014-01-03
2   2   2014-08-01
3   3   2014-08-01
4   4   2014-06-02
5   5   2014-06-06
6   6   2014-06-06
7   7   2014-08-08
8   8   2014-08-08
9   9   2014-04-08
10  10  2013-12-09
11  11  2014-09-10
12  12  2014-09-12
```

How can I reconcile this mess?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could convert the 'date' column to 'Date' class, extract the 'year' to create a logical index ('indx') for years 2013, 2014).

```
df$date <- as.Date(df$date)
indx <- !format(df$date, '%Y') %in% 2013:2014
```

By using `lubridate`, convert to 'Date' class using `dmy` after removing the first two characters.

```
library(lubridate)
df$date[indx] <- dmy(sub('^..', '', df$date[indx]))
df
#   id       date
#1   1 2014-01-03
#2   2 2014-08-01
#3   3 2014-08-01
#4   4 2014-06-02
#5   5 2014-06-06
#6   6 2014-06-06
#7   7 2014-08-08
#8   8 2014-08-08
#9   9 2014-04-08
#10 10 2013-12-09
#11 11 2014-09-10
#12 12 2014-09-12
```

Comment: It works! But could you explain what's going on here? I've never seen `(..)(..)(.{4})(..)` and `\\1\\4\\3\\2`.

Comment: I'm getting: `Warning message: In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, indx, value = c(7L, NA, NA, 8L, NA, NA,  :invalid factor level, NA generated`

Comment: @user3731467 Did you first converted the `date` to `Date` class?  ie. `df$date <- as.Date(df$date)`.  I don't get error by using the input data you showed

Comment: I think something is backwards here... The basis for modification shouldn't be that day is in c(13, 14), but rather that year in _not_ in c(2013, 2014)!

Comment: @DominicComtois  I did this based on the OP's post `if the date ends with a -14 or -13 it should really be 2014 and 2013`.  Also, I don't find any difference between my output and the OP's expected one.

Comment: Yeah, but think about it: if he has a large df, chances are sometimes you'll hit a `2014-12-13` which would be valid, but still transformed by this code...

Comment: @DominicComtois You're right. My df has 300K observations. There's definitely a 2014-12-13 in there.

Comment: @user3731467 This sub would get you `sub('(..)(..)(.{4})(..)', '\\1\\4\\3\\2', '2014-12-13')#[1] "2013-12-14"`.  But, I think you should have specified the problem more accurately.

Comment: I added an edit to the original question to avoid further confusion.

Comment: Ok. I didn't respond because I don't think it's important, simply. Anyhow, all is fine for me too, let's keep up the good work ;)

Answer (score 3):

Package `lubridate` has the convenient function `year` that will be useful here.

```
library(lubridate)

# Convert date to proper date class variable
df$date <- as.Date(df$date)

# Isolate problematic indices; when year is not in 2013 or 2014,
# we'll go to and from character representation. We'll trim
# the "20" in front of the "false year" and then specify the 
# proper format to read the character back into a Date class.

tmp.indices <- which(!year(df$date) %in% c("2013", "2014"))
df$date[tmp.indices] <- as.Date(substring(as.character(df$date[tmp.indices]),
                                first = 3), format = "%d-%m-%y")
```

Result:

```
   id       date
1   1 2014-01-03
2   2 2014-08-01
3   3 2014-08-01
4   4 2014-06-02
5   5 2014-06-06
6   6 2014-06-06
7   7 2014-08-08
8   8 2014-08-08
9   9 2014-04-08
10 10 2013-12-09
11 11 2014-09-10
12 12 2014-09-12
```